# MIG Welding Wire feed speed calculation

Tags: experimental-physics

I want to calculate the wire-feed speed only using output current of the welding machine is it possible ? if so what is the formula ?

Known parameters

1. Weld Current
2. Weld Voltage
3. Diameter of wire
4. Density of material

Comment: This question might be more appropriate over on https://diy.stackexchange.com they have a welding tag.

Comment: One question would be - how much welding have you done? Why do you think output current is the only parameter of interest in wire feed?